# css layout - 2 column, dynamic width problem

Tags: html, css

My problem has todo with a dynamically loaded image in col1 and resizing col2 to fill the rest of the space.

the width of container is fixed at 950px.

col1's width could be any with.

```
┌────────────── container ─────────────┐
│  ┌──── col1 ────┐  ┌──── col2 ────┐  │
│  │ Image        │  │ Text         │  │
│  │              │  │              │  │
│  └──────────────┘  └──────────────┘  │
└──────────────────────────────────────┘



┌────────────── container ─────────────┐
│  ┌──── col1 ────────┐  ┌── col2 ──┐  │
│  │ Image            │  │ Text     │  │
│  │                  │  │          │  │
│  └──────────────────┘  └──────────┘  │
└──────────────────────────────────────┘
```

I've tryed solving it using tables and div float, but haven't had any success.
this is an example of the page i'm working with..

http://www.camoconnell.com/#17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the td {width:100%;} inside your basic.css , btw the site looks cool but html is bad :D